# acceder a variables y funciones del cliente via consola

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, consola, depuración, cliente

tengo una pregunta conceptual sobre web.
cuando abro las herramientas de desarrollo de cualquier navegador web, puedo acceder a la solapa depurador y ver la estrucutra de archivos solicitados al servidor.
ahora bien, sobre esos archivos, ¿como los accedo desde consola? ¿es posible?
adjunto imagen de lo que planteo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esto es de la pagina de npm. desde mi lado (cliente) veo todo los js's que se pidieron al servidor. ¿como accedo a la variable "g" exportada por el modulo "global.js" usando la consola? porque imagino que hay una manera, ya que la consola tambien corre del lado del cliente.

¡saludos y gracias por leer!

Comment: Solo escribe `g`

Answer (score 0):

En este caso particular, `global.js` no existe realmente en el cliente, al menos no es lo que se ejecuta literalmente, porque **Webpack** hace un "empaquetado" en un archivo tipo `commons.7c929e35968b599aa68d.js`, lo que ves es un mapeo del origen, algo asi como una "reconstrucción" de los archivos originales.  Para acceder e interactuar con esos archivos, puedes usar las herramientas de depuración que vienen con los navegadores, porjemplo los "breakpoints".
En Chrome, si haces click sobre el número de línea (porejemplo la 20), verás el código que realmente carga el navegador.

En cuanto a interactuar con `g` desde la consola, entiendo que tienes que ver en `commons.7c929e35968b599aa68d.js` a que corresponde, pero no es una tarea muy sencilla.